# Selenium driver is freezing by switching tabs in browser

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to parse several goods. The problem is I can parse only first element.

To be specific: I need goods which were sorted by "Newest" on the website below. And I click this button before parsing.

```
   driver.get("https://www.banggood.com/new-arrivals.html");
   driver.findElementByCssSelector("body > div.lastest-box.J-loading-box > div > ul.filtrate.J-filter-list > li:nth-child(2)").click();
```

So I want to get info about each good doing like:

```
    // save goods in arrayList
    List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();


    WebElement ulElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.box > ul.prt-list.J-prt-list"));
    List<WebElement> liElements = industries.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    // using loop for parsing
    for (WebElement element : liElements) {
        String price = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.price-box > span.price.notranslate")).getText();
        String title = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.title")).getText();
        String url = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.img > a")).getAttribute("href");
        // switch link to get img 
        String newUrl = url.replace("https://www.banggood.com/new-arrivals.html", url);

        // open new tab using another url
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        driver.get(newUrl);
        WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.id("landingImage"));
        String srcImg = img.getAttribute("src");


        articleList.add(new Article(srcImg, url, title, price));

        // close new tab and back to the main window
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close()");
    }

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Via debug I see it works:

[image]

but loop is going through only first element then the program is freezing. And I don't see any issues in the console.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your driver is freezing because it is searching for a window that doesn't exist anymore. After closing your window you need to explicitly switch your window back to the first window:

```
// close new tab and back to the main window 
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close()");
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```